# Lua string.gsub with a hyphen

Tags: string, lua, gsub

I have two strings - each string has many lines like the following:

```
value_1 = "DEFAULT-VLAN"
value_2 = "WAN"
data = "HOSTNAME = DEFAULT-VLAN"
result = string.gsub(data,value_1,value_2)
print(result)
```

Result:

```
data = "HOSTNAME = DEFAULT-VLAN"
```

When the hyphen ("-") is deleted from the value it is working.
Is there an easy way to solve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`-` is a magic character in Lua patterns. You need to escape it.

Change

```
value_1 = "DEFAULT-VLAN"
```

to:

```
value_1 = "DEFAULT%-VLAN"
```

Comment: Why am I getting `nil` for this? `string.find("evs%-admin%-loggedstatistics%.csv", "evs%-admin%-loggedstatistics%.csv")`

Comment: @codingkapoor Magic characters here are for patterns, not literal strings. Remove all `%` in the first argument of `string.find`.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `string.gsub` takes a pattern similar to Regex—it does not do a "literal" replacement; this means you need to prefix any characters that have a special meaning with `%` to escape them.

A list of special characters that need escaping for the pattern are: `(`, `)`, `.`, `+`, `-`, `*`, `?`, `[`, `]`, `^`, `$`, and `%`.  For the replacement string, only `%` has a special meaning.  With this, we can write a replace function that sanitizes the inputs.

```
local function replace(str, what, with)
    what = string.gsub(what, "[%(%)%.%+%-%*%?%[%]%^%$%%]", "%%%1") -- escape pattern
    with = string.gsub(with, "[%%]", "%%%%") -- escape replacement
    return string.gsub(str, what, with)
end
```

And then you can:

```
result = replace(data, value_1, value_2)
```