# Replacing string in string with special characters

Tags: replace, lua

I'm trying to replace a string with special characters with a new one.

For example:

```
path = "assets/test-image-filename.jpg"
filename = "test-image-filename.jpg"
newFilename = "new-filename.jpg"
newPath = path:gsub(filename, newFilename)
```

I know I must escape special characters like `-` with `%`, but the filename is in a variable I got after splitting the path.

Comment: I think the answers found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072601/lua-string-gsub-with-a-hyphen) will help you.  I think the second answer specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Timothy G.'s comment can help. I myself was writing something like this (two lines added to your code, actually one line):

```
path = "assets/test-image-filename.jpg"
filename = "test-image-filename.jpg"
newFilename = "new-filename.jpg"

filename = filename:gsub('%W', '%%%1')
-- newFilename = newFilename:gsub('%W', '%%%1') -- no need to do the same for repl string

newPath = path:gsub(filename, newFilename)
```

`%W` means any non-alphanumeric characters and `%1` the first captured string. See [6.4.1 of Lua Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1).

Comment: Thank you for the explanations! The answer of the post was complicated to understand. This one is simpler to understand.

Comment: The replacement string in gsub does not use % the same way, so no need to do the: `newFilename = newFilename:gsub('%W', '%%%1')` part.

Comment: @tonypdmtr Oops, you're right. I modified the answer.